# I have a usestate that I want to set I want to set to a value !==null within a function

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am trying to set a state var within a function so when a form button is pressed, the value of the usestate will not equal null anymore. Because the form will not equal null this will perform a different action in my code if this button has been pressed.

Only issue is it seems the variable setReg cannot be set inside of a function as it will not be a global variable. Is there a workaround here?

```js
//the usestate
const [Reg, setReg] = useState(null)

//the function
const updateEthers = () => {
  let tempProvider = new ethers.providers.Web3Provider(window.ethereum);
  setProvider(tempProvider);

  let tempSigner = tempProvider.getSigner();
  setSigner(tempSigner);


  //Here I am saying if setreg is null as set in the state then perform this

  if (setReg == null) {
    let tempContract = new ethers.Contract(
      phonecontractAddress,
      Register_abi,
      tempSigner)
    setContract(tempContract)
  }

  //Else use a different function
  else {
    let
      tempContract = new ethers.Contract(
        codecontractAddress,
        Code_abi,
        tempSigner)
    setContract(tempContract)
  }
}


//I have a button when pressed calls this

const setRegister = async (event) => {
  event.preventDefault();
  const Hash = await ipfsbcupload(event.target.setText.value);
  console.log("sending " + event.target.setText.value + " to the contract");
  contract.set(Hash);
  setPhoneNum(event.target.setText.value)
  let setReg = 1

  //let setReg = 1 so that the setReg will no longer be null is the theory so the form will choose the other option when pressed now.
  //...
}
```

Comment: `setReg== null` doesn't make sense, `setReg` is always a function and never `null`. Did you mean to test `Reg == null`?

Comment: `let setReg = 1` makes no sense either. Did you mean to just call `setReg(1);`? Currently you're declaring a local variable inside the `setRegister` function that has nothing to do with your component state at all.

Comment: I should of added I am new to this haha so thats probably why its not making sense :D. I am stumped with this one. Is there another way to set the state of the onclick button ?

Comment: There are many other ways, but this is the React way.

Answer (score 0):

`setReg()` is available globally; however you're missing the function brackets at the end (`setReg` vs `setReg()`). That said, what I believe you want to reference is `reg`.

```
/* Note that I've made `reg` lowercase to follow camelCase rules */
const [reg, setReg] = useState(null)

const updateEthers = () => {

   // this will run fine and is likely the code you want
   if (reg == null) { }

   // this will return an error - setReg is a function and so needs the parentheses behind it as setReg() - otherwise it will say it's not defined
   if (setReg == null) { }

   // this doesn't make sense because setReg is just setting what reg should be, it's not a value itself
   if (setReg() == null) { }

}
```